# How to redirect to another page on ng-click using angularjs or coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, coffeescript

I am doing some tasks now in angularjs and coffeescript. I have a requirement like: I have couple of buttons in my html page like:

```
<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="button1();">Button1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="button2();">Button2</button>
</div>
```

If I click on Button1, then it should redirect to another page(like: '/test1.html'), similarly, if I click on Button2, then it should redirect to another page(like: '/test2.html').
How can I do this in AngularJS/CoffeeScript ?

If I do in my coffeescript file, I am getting the below error:

```
app = angular.module('myApp', dependencies)
app.controller 'WizardController', [
  '$scope',
  ($scope) ->
  $scope.button1 = ->
    window.location = '/test1.html'
    return

    $scope.button2 = ->
    window.location = '/test2.html'
    return
  ]
```

but it is giving compilation error at return statement: Compilation error: Parse error on line 103: Unexpected 'TERMINATOR'

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect straight from your HTML page:

```
<div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-href="/test1.html">Button1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-href="/test1.html">Button2</button>
</div>
```

Or else in your code you should remove the ';' from the

> ng-click

as in:

```
<div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="button1()">Button1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="button2()">Button2</button>
</div>
```

I will also check the indentation in your coffeescript as it tend to be a bit fuzzy.

```
app = angular.module('myApp', dependencies)
app.controller 'WizardController', [ '$scope', '$location',
($scope, $location) ->
  $scope.button1 = ->
    $location.path('/test1.html')

  $scope.button2 = ->
    $location.path('/test2.html')
]
```

Comment: ng-href is a good solution, but a note is needed: dont use window.location while using angular, just use $location.

Comment: Hi Thanks you all, I have done like above, but I am still getting error(at $location.path line): Parse error on line 218: Unexpected 'INDENT'  And If add ng-href, it is not working also.

Comment: As I said in my post, indentation is very important in coffeescript. Check my edited js file, also in your file, select all an then convert indentation into spaces.

Comment: Indentation error is resolved now, but I cannot able to redirect to another page still if I use the code like above

Comment: The error is: Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $controllerProvider from myApp  and also $scope is not defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97842/discussion-between-jax-and-dhana).

Comment: Got a solution at: http://jsfiddle.net/eqc3Latm/ . It may helpful to anyone ! Thanks all !!

Comment: Just noticed you were looking to have tabs in your view, Your question does not reflect this fact. Nonetheless you could use [Angular-Ui Tabs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs)