# Angularjs - Struggling to link a button to show the next component

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to link a button to open a new HTML component but no matter which method I've tried I cannot get it to work

First I tried a JS Function:

```
function openNext(){
window.location = '../nextpage.html';


 }
```

on this button code:

```
<div class="content">
  <button type="button" ng-click="openNext()" class="nextBtn mat-raised-button"> Next!</button>
</div>
```

But that didn't do anything, so tried a simple href link, still nothing.

So I thought it was something perhaps with the routing

Comment: can you check this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/34263743/9970857

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you are only asking to load a component on the click of a button. Nothing simpler:

```
<div class="content">
  <button type="button" ng-click="openNext()" class="nextBtn mat-raised-button"> Next!</button>
   <the-html-component-you-want-to-open
      ng-if="isMyComponentOpen == true"
   ></the-html-component-you-want-to-open>
</div>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.isMyComponentOpen = false;
$scope.openNext = function() {
   $scope.isMyComponentOpen = true;
}
```

On the other hand, if you are looking into switching pages in your application, or loading external dialogs/modals containing other components, then you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, yea it is switching a page is what I'm trying to do

Comment: ok, then you should look into angularjs router https://www.npmjs.com/package/@uirouter/angularjs